# jQuery retornando r.fn.init()] erro estranho

Tags: jquery

Então, estava fazendo um projeto de escola e me deparei com um erro bem estranho no jQuery.

Eu repeti basicamente a mesma etapa de programação e a partir da terceira vez o código não funciona.

Tentei identificar o que era retornado no console e recebi esse código estranho.

Não sei explicar direito, talvez vendo uma demo fique melhor.

A select da esquerda habilita a da direita e assim por diante. Entretanto, a select Frente não habilita Capítulo e nem Capítulo habilita TipoEx.

[image: Teste de identificação pelo console]

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrx08vu8/)**

Comment: Tenho a leve impressão que é por causa da acentuação, pois não é aconselhável

Comment: Eu imaginei que pudesse ser a acentuação e testei sem, mas obtive o mesmo resultado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os erros são basicamente de desatenção.

Alguns problemas no código:

- Você acrescentou # ao id em Capítulo e TipoEx. Na hora de chamar o objeto, ele obviamente não iria localizar.
- Ainda em Capítulo, você não usou acentuação, mas fez o select no objeto como se tivesse posto.
- Você tentou localizar $('#tipoEx') com t minúsculo, o que também não vai funcionar.

O objeto que você vê no retorno, ao executar um select jQuery para Capítulo e TipoEx indicam que ele não foi localizado, apenas.

Normalize como abaixo e tudo funcionará bem.

```
<select id='Capítulo' size='3' disabled>
    <option>Capitulo 1</option>
    <option>Capitulo 2</option>
    <option>Capitulo 3</option>
</select>

<select id='TipoEx' size='3' disabled>
    <option>Revisando</option>
    <option>Propostos</option>
    <option>Complementares</option>
</select>

$('#Capítulo').click(function() {
    capitulo = $(this).find(':selected').text();
    $('#navigation a.capitulo').text(capitulo);
    if (capitulo != '') {
        $('#navigation a:eq(3)').addClass('active');
        $('#TipoEx').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});

$('#TipoEx').click(function() {
    tipoEx = $(this).find(':selected').text();
    $('#navigation a.tipoEx').text(tipoEx);
    if (capitulo != '') {
        $('#Exercícios').show();
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Realmente foi desatenção, muito obrigado pela ajuda!